# ReactiveUi Memoryleak using ReactiveList viewinjection

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

The setup i prepared is quite simple.
I have a shellview which gets populated with a view which just holds a Listbox which is bound to a reactivelist

```
public LacquerProductionOrderListView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            this.WhenActivated(
                d =>
                {
                    this.
                    OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.LacquerProductionOrders,
                        v => v.LacquerProductionOrderList.ItemsSource)
                        .AddTo(d);
                });
        }
```

The Viewmodel is also quite simple and just for testing purposes.

```
    public LacquerProductionOrderListViewModel()
    {
        this.activator = new ViewModelActivator();


        LacquerProductionOrders = new ReactiveList<LacquerProductionOrderViewModel>();



        var c1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
           .ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
           .Subscribe(_ => LacquerProductionOrders.AddRange(new List<LacquerProductionOrderViewModel>()

        {
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0)),
            new LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(new ProductionOrder(null, "foo", 0, 0, 0))
        }
               )
        );

        var c = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7))
            //.ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
            .Subscribe(_ => LacquerProductionOrders.Clear());

        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            c.AddTo(d);
            c1.AddTo(d);

        });

    }
```

So it populates the list and clears it. My problem now is, that the destructor oft he

```
    public LacquerProductionOrderViewModel(ProductionOrder productionOrder)
    {
        this.activator = new ViewModelActivator();

        _productionOrder = productionOrder;

    }

    ~LacquerProductionOrderViewModel()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("destructor called.");
    }
```

Is never called, so the memoryconsumption of the application is growing quite fast. Maybe you can tell me where I am mistaken or what I could do better.

So my workaround is to use an

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
<DataTemplate> 
...
</DataTemplate> 
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

instead of regsitering a view for the viewmodels in the list. That works but obviosly it would be much nicer to be able to use injected views/viewmodels.

kind regards

Comment: Usually destructors are not declared for C# classes. To release the resources we use `IDisposable` interface. When finishing the object lifecycle, `object.Dispose()` is called to free the resources. Try that, I think ReactiveUI supports disposables.

Comment: I just declared the destructor to easily see if the viewmodel was destroyed or not. Implementing IDisposable also did not help with the issue.